How to prove that any Schwarz distribution is can be represented by hyper-function?
As far as I understand hyper-functions are generalizations for distributions (at least in 1-dimensional case and for some "good enough" definition of distribution...). What is the simplest way to prove that?

Suppose we have distribution on unit circle (that is AFAIU element of L_2(D) space), how one can construct hyper-function representing it?

"Suppose we have distribution on unit disk" - do you mean unit circle?
